# SQL select sum from multiple tables without JOIN

Tags: sql

I have several tables with the same structure. How can I select SUM(field) from these tables without JOIN (just simply union the tables)?

For example, if I run:

```
SELECT SUM(views) FROM tb1, tb2 WHERE 1
```

It tells me "Column 'views' in field list is ambiguous".

Is there a way to use `UNION`?

Comment: Are you trying to get one value from all of the tables? or where the table synch up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should get you:

```
SELECT SUM(views)
FROM (
    SELECT views FROM table1
        UNION ALL
    SELECT views FROM table2
) A
```

The reason you're getting an error is because you're making a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (all rows in one table are matched to all rows in the other table), and since both tables have a `view` column, it doesn't know which you're taking about.  However, that Cartesian join will (probably) not give you the sum you're looking for.

Comment: Add an alias to each table,                                      i.e. FROM table1 AS T1, FROM table2 as T2

Comment: You actually just have to add a correlation name to the subquery.  I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is the same:

```
SELECT SUM(views) 
FROM (tb1 UNION tb2)
WHERE 1
```

If that doesn't work, try (I don't have a mysql handy to test it):

```
SELECT SUM(views) 
FROM (
    (SELECT views FROM tb1) 
    UNION 
    (SELECT views FROM tb2)
    )
WHERE 1
```

Comment: Union supresses duplicate values, you will get a false sum, if one value appears in multiple columns.

Comment: True, but you can use UNION ALL to not suppress duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(views) FROM 
(
  SELECT views FROM tb1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT views FROM tb2
) t
```